# TFS 2010 Project portal shows "Login failed for user <DOMAIN>\sharepoint.admin" error message. How do I fix this?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, portal

At the bottom of every project portal dashboard page for my **newly created** TFS 2010 project portal (*MSF Agile v5.0 template*) I get the message "**login failed for [DOMAIN]\sharepoint.admin**" (see picture)

[image]

If I edit any of the dashboard pages (site actions of edit page) this message is still there, but not inside a web part which leads me to belive this is not a web part that is showing this message. But what is it?  More to the point what do I need to do to fix it?

I presume I have some permissions or configuration issues, but currently both I and my companies internal support people are without a clue as to how we go about diagnosing never mind resolving this issue.

It should be pointed out that i/we are TFS 2010 newbies AND sharepoint 2007 newbies.
Any help would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the solution [Roel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3257/roel-hans-bethlehem) (aswered via sharepoint stack overflow site).

[image: fixed portal]

Setting sharepoint.admin as a TFS contributor seems to have done the trick; once enough time was elapsed to have the warehose refresh.